# blocking skype through websense

Tags: skype, websense

How do I block Skype using Websense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype is blocked by default after installation of Websense Express.

In the Websense Master Database, Skype is assigned to the protocol category called P2P File Sharing. This category is blocked by the policy Basic Security, which is set by default after Websense Express is installed. So check in your Master Database under P2P File Sharing and ensure that it is blocked.

Comment: i never got around to this, but we somehow got it, so i'll assume thats one of solutions